# MAUI dependency errors

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, maui

### My issue:

I decided to build a .NET MAUI application. I installed the `.NET Multi-Platform App UI Development` and the `.NET Desktop Development` workloads. I did not at all alter my installation.

Here's the issue I'm facing (all dependencies have a yellow warning triangle with exclamation mark):

[image: Issue]

Edit: Right clicking on the dependencies prompts me to update them. After looking at the NuGet package manager, there are not updates. Even if I manually click on the packages.

And the error:

```
Error   NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks, even though they have specified a platform: net7.0-maccatalyst
```

It appears in the `.csproj` file.

The error though, is not very important to me, as I will only be building for Windows for now. If I wouldn't have disabled mobile platforms, it would show the error for them aswell.

### What I've tried:

I tried reinstalling the workloads and completely re-creating the project but nothing worked. As soon as the project is created the errors appear.
I also found some other posts about this issue, but none worked or helped. They also mostly had no answer to them at all.

My Visual Studio version is
`Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.5 (Stable)`
and I'm using
`.NET 7` on `Windows 10 22H2 19045.2965`

Comment: Paste text of error message into question. So people can search for that text. Since it is complaining about MacCatalyst, try UNCHECKING that platform in Project Properties. That won’t fix the Windows dependencies, but it seems best to first try to get just Windows working. Sorry, not sure what else to do.

Comment: You could use ```dotnet workload list``` to see if all necessary workloads have been installed.

Comment: The workloads are there. As I said,  have all the required workloads to create .NET and MAUI applications.

Comment: I will paste the errors into the post tomorrow.

Comment: You may try uninstall and then install the workloads.  Refer to [dotnet workload command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT  I already did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not like the solution, but you have to completely repair Visual Studio. Reinstalling workloads does not help.

Here's how to repair Visual Studio:
[Repair Visual Studio - Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

In my case resolved in **Visual Studio** - command

*Show -> Terminal* (open terminal in Visual Studio)

and write `dotnet restore MySolution.sln`

Hint: MySolution - change your project name :-)